# Dialog addContentView at the end of the dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

In my application I have a Dialog. Let's say I have created a Dialog with a custom View and now I want to add a second view to it, directly under the first view. I tried it with this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View test = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, null, false);

dialog.addContentView(buttons, test.getLayoutParams());
```

But if I add the second view with this code, it appears at the top of the other view. I want that the second view is directly under the first. Here is my layout for the second view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NONE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The root layout from my Dialog is a FrameLayout but I can not realy change it to another layout. Do you have any ideas how I can set the second view under the first and not on the top of the dialog?

Comment: FrameLayout doesn't support putting one layout below another one -- it only supports overlays, with gravity. You'll have to use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to put the second layout underneath the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

So you should probably not give it a child because it's not gonna get easier. That being said, why don't you add the second view to the ViewGroup inside the `FrameLayout`? Thats the best I can offer unless I see the other ViewGroups. It sounds like you have constraints, and without knowing more its hard to give you a specific answer without knowing why.